# How to load the anglularjs app by using jquery load funcrion

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, ngroute

I have 3 html applications

1. http://localhost/apphost/app1/index.html ( just tables )
2. http://localhost/apphost/app2/index.html ( simple AngularJS )
3. http://localhost/apphost/app3/index.html ( simple AngularJS with
   routes )

I have an apphost.html file with links pointing to each of them, and they are loaded via ajax on 
the content area. It works on app1, but when the content is AngularJS I am geting an error.

I need this to work where an AngularJS application is loaded via AJAX.

apphost.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>::: all apps :::</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" >
    <a href="app1/index.html" class="btn btn-default" role="button" id="app1"  >App 1</a>
    <a href="app2/index.html" class="btn btn-default" role="button" id="app2"  >App 2</a>
    <a href="app3/index.html" class="btn btn-default" role="button" id="app3"  >App 3</a>
</div>

<div id="contentarea">

</div>


<script>   


$(document).on( "click", ".btn", function() {  
 $("#contentarea").load($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

app2/index.html

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.author = {
    'name' : 'Ray Villalobos',
    'title' : 'Staff Author',
    'company' : 'Lynda.com'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller = "MyController">
   <h1>{{employee.name}}</h1>
 </div>


</div>




  <script>   
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.employee = {
     'name' : 'ronnie mund'
   }
 });  

  </script>
```

app3/index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Demo</title>
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main" ng-view></div>

  <script>   
   //:::::::::::::::::: app ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
   'ngRoute',
   'myControllers'
 ]);

 myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
   when('/list', {
     templateUrl: 'list.html',
     controller: 'listController'
   }).
   when('/details/:itemId', {
     templateUrl: 'details.html',
     controller: 'detailsController'
   }).
   otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/list'
   });
 }]);

   //:::::::::::::::::: controller ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

 myControllers.controller('listController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.artists = data;
     $scope.artistOrder = 'name';
   });
 }]);

 myControllers.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
   $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.artists = data;
     $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;

     if ($routeParams.itemId > 0) {
       $scope.prevItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)-1;
     } else {
       $scope.prevItem = $scope.artists.length-1;
     }

     if ($routeParams.itemId < $scope.artists.length-1) {
       $scope.nextItem = Number($routeParams.itemId)+1;
     } else {
       $scope.nextItem = 0;
     }

   });
 }]);

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Folder structure
[image]

[Please get Source code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9r3z521nsckqx9z/apphost.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

To manually load your angular app, you can bootstrap it manually like below

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);    
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
 });
```

Comment: I need when you click the App2 link that time app2 loaded on contentarea div. If you want i will give you source code.